# Resetting dropdown by manual subscription doesn't work depending on what observable was subscribed to

Tags: knockout.js

I searched online and tried to think hard and understand this behavior but I still can't figure out why this is the behavior. May be I am missing something basic here?

I'd appreciate some pointers/resources/answers.

Consider this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/e3cTT/

Why does this reset the product selection

```
// Whenever the category changes, reset the product selection
self.category.subscribe(function() {
    self.productName(undefined);
});
```

While this does not?

```
// Whenever the category changes, reset the product selection
self.categoryName.subscribe(function() {
    self.productName(undefined);
});
```

Comment: According to your script, `categoryName` is the selected `option` where `category` is the `select` itself. Resetting the `select` parent does nothing, it's the `option` that must be manipulated.

Comment: I didn't get it. Actually, `category` is not the `select`, it is a computed observable based on `categoryName`. Yes, `categoryName` is indeed the selected option of the Kendo dropdown whose data source is `sampleProductCategories`(and not `category`). Also, what do you mean by "Resetting the `select` parent does nothing". I am not resetting any `select` parent. I am resetting the `productName` which I expect to result the selection of the products kendo dropdownlist to reset. It's resetting in one case and not in the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has to do with the order in which the `subscribe` event is called relative to the other `computed` properties. `Computed` and `subscribe`d properties are called in the same order that they are written whenever there is a change on the observed property. Here is a basic timeline of what's happening in each case, as best as I can tell (haven't read the kendo source so there's some guesswork):

**category.subscribe:**

1. Category dropdown is manipulated by the user, new value is set
2. `categoryName` observable is updated by knockout
3. `category` computed property is updated due to the change in `categoryName`
4. `product` computed property is updated due to the change in `category`

   Note: `productName` is still the old value at this point
5. `category.subscribe` event is called, changing value of `productName`
6. `product` computed property is updated due to the change in `productName`

   Note: `productName` is `undefined` now
7. All dependent computed properties and subscribed events have been completed on `category`, so `kendoDropDownList` is updated based on new `products` list and the current (`undefined`) value of `productName`

**categoryName.subscribe:**

1. Category dropdown is manipulated by the user, new value is set
2. `categoryName` observable is updated by knockout
3. `category` computed property is updated due to the change in `categoryName`
4. `product` computed property is updated due to the change in `category`

   Note: `productName` is still the old value at this point
5. All dependent computed properties and subscribed events have been completed on `category`, so `kendoDropDownList` is updated based on new `products` list and the current (*not* `undefined`) value of `productName`

   I tested `kendoDropDownList` and it selects the first option even if you have the `productName` set to a dummy string like `'asdf'`. It only shows as blank if the value is the empty string (`''`) or `undefined`.
6. `categoryName.subscribe` event is called, changing value of `productName`
7. `product` computed property is updated due to the change in `productName`

   Note: `productName` is `undefined` now
8. `category` does *not* update again because it is not dependent on `product` or `productName`, however the `kendoDropDownList` should update but does not.

   Upon further testing, `kendoDropDownList` will only show as blank when the value is `undefined` or `''` at the time the drop down first gets created (in this example, that's in step 5). If you add an `optionLabel` argument to the `kendoDropDownList` it will work as expected, however.

---

If you put the `categoryName.subscribe` first, before the `category = ko.computed(...)`, then the `productName` would be set to `undefined` before the whole cycle begins which would be one way to fix it. Here's a fiddle showing just that: http://jsfiddle.net/6Z6TW/

Another way is to add an `optionLabel` parameter to the `kendoDropDownList` options hash as noted in step 8.

Comment: Marked this as the answer. Unable to vote up because I am new to SO. I was experimenting and #8 is what I had thought too. Thank you for confirming. I was not aware of the order being taken into account. I was not sure about asking this question initially, but I am so glad I did. Thank you for the detailed explanation and taking the time to look into this. It really really helped me. Thanks!

Comment: No problem! I added a little more detail to step 8 just now that might clear some more things up as well.

Comment: Wow, that's some crazy stuff. :) Thank you again!